# Zend Framework: Use a distinct controller to render a part on layout of webpage

Tags: zend-framework

I'm beginning with Zend framework, so i'm trying to create a webpage with it. I already have my layout, and as i understand `echo $this->layout()->content;` will load view of default controller: IndexController. So now, i want to have a frame for my login/logout/signup function at a corner of my webpage. Of course, i want to that frame is always shown. My ideal is create a new controller and views, however i don't know how to make my layout render views of that new controller to my selected corner of webpage. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my favorite method :

you can use ActionStack Action Helper from your controller to call a new "login" action located in another controller (named "components" for example)

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper( 'actionStack' )->actionToStack( 'login', 'components' )
```

Create your "login" action in your "componentsController" :

```
public function loginAction()
{
    //... type your code here
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setResponseSegment( 'hereIstheLoginBlock' );
}
```

Don't forget to create a view for this new component in APPLICATION_PATH /views/scripts/components/login.phtml

Finally, somewhere in the view of your page, you can call :

```
echo $this->layout()->hereIstheLoginBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make folder `views/scripts/template`
2. There make a file named `login.phtml`
3. Then use this view helper `$this->partial('template/login.phtml')`

Good Luck!))

Comment: but how to use controller? and load result views of that controller to my expected area???? i think your above solve is only render a partial view to webpage.